# Distance function on a curve on a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose that we are given a non-negative even function $b\in C^\infty[-1,1]$ satisfying $b(0)=0$, $\sqrt{b(x+y)}\le \sqrt{b(x)}+\sqrt{b(y)}$ for any $x,y\in[-\frac12,\frac12]$. Can we always find a 3-dimensional smooth Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and a smooth curve $a:[-\frac12,\frac12]\to M$ parametrized by arc length, such that the square of the distance function $d_g(a(t),a(s))^2=b(t-s)$?

For example, if we set $(M,g)=(\mathbb{R}^3,\|\cdot\|)$, can we find a smooth curve $a:[-\frac12,\frac12]\to \mathbb{R}^3$ parametrized by arc length, such that the square of the distance function $\|a(t)-a(s)\|^2=b(t-s)$?

Comment: There is an obvious obstruction from the triangular inequality.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Thanks. I forgot to write a condition on $b$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "no".

Take $b(x)=x^2-x^{1000}$.

Assume that there is a manifolds with the required curve $a$.
Note that $a$ has vanishing geodesic curvature; in particular $a$ is a geodesic.
On the other hand, no arc of $a$ is length-minimizing, a contradiction.